# Return response HTTP response code for pass and fail

Tags: java, spring, api

I am new to spring boot and want to return response code if my program executes successfully and if it fails

i am trying to send 2 numbers via POST method and get the sum. If addition happens return response code and a string saying pass.

if it fails return response code and fail.

```
Controller class

@PostMapping 
(value="/add",consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
public int add(@RequestBody Numbers num) {
    int sum=num.getNum1()+num.getNum2();
    return sum;

}
```

input 
{"num1":1,
"num2":2}
output :
{code:200
status:Pass}

input 2 {
"num1":"abch",
"num2":2}

output:
{code:500(or whatever is returned),
status:fail

Comment: Any idea on ResponseEntity?

Comment: @Deadpoolcan you guide me on that please

Answer (score 0):

1. Define xxxexception

   ```
   class  extends RuntimeException
   xxxException extends RuntimeException {
       private int code = 0;
       private String title = '';
   }
   ```
2. ```
   try {
      xxxx
   }cache(Exception e) {
      throw xxxException.newException(e.getMessage()) 
   }
   ```